# How To Stop a Recursion and Return to Main function

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I have the following code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int rec(int p)
{
    if(p==0)
    return 0;
    
    rec(p-1);
    
    if(p==3)
    exit(0);
    
    cout<< "The value of p is "<< p<<endl;  
    
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int x=rec(5);
    cout<<"Printing from main"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print only for `p==1` and `p==2` in the recursive function and then return to the main function and print the line `Printing from main`. What is the proper way to do so?

Comment: The typical way to do this is simply `return`, but you have to check the return condition at the beginning of the function before you potentially recurse again.  Alternatively you could `throw` something and `catch` it in `main`, but that is arguably a hack.

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect, [`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) is working correctly; the code is using `exit` incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, yes, true. I have framed it wrong. Let me edit

Comment: When you hover over it, the downvote button says “This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.”  I’m not the downvoter, but there’s no obligation on SO to explain the downvote in more detail than that.

Comment: My first impression is that your function is strangely constructed. It looks like recursion was forced upon a problem that did not deserve it. If that's the case, then a question based on that code is **not useful** since the code should not be used. Second, I noticed that your text mentions desired behavior when `p` is `1` or `2`, yet the checks inside your function are for `0` or `3`. That contributes to being **unclear**. Third, the ratio of text to code is rather low. While that alone is not a reason to downvote, such a low ratio is often the result of inadequate understanding/research.

Comment: I should note that my previous comment is conjecture. I did not downvote because the current (negative) score looks fair to me and I think it does not deserve to be sent lower.

Comment: I still do not see how your functional requirements justify recursion. In fact, what you seem to want is accomplished by removing the recursive call, as in `int rec(int p)
{
    if ( p == 1  ||  p == 2 )
        cout << "The value of p is " << p << endl;
    return 0;
}`.
I have come to the conclusion that the intended question has not been adequately described.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return after printing `1` or `2`, would terminating the recursion work? In that case, you can use the code below, and stop the recursion in case you encounter `1` or `2`.

Also, as the code in the question is, `x` is not used.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int rec(int p)
{
   if (p <= 0) {
      return 0;
   } else if (p == 1 || p == 2) {
      cout << "The value of p is " << p << endl;
      return p;
   } else {
      return rec(p - 1);
   }
}


int main()
{
    int x{rec(5)};
    cout << "Printing from main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, but my intention for this question was to see if we can actually break the recursion and return to main. This code of yours serves the purpose of printing the desire output but it still executes the entire stack frame.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return rec(p - 1);`?

Comment: @MohanSingh You can't "break" a recursion and return to some arbitrary place. Recursive functions work *exactly* like non-recursive functions; you can only return to the place where you were called.

Comment: To jump out of multiple stack frames and get all the way back to `main`, use `throw`/`catch`.  This is useful, for example, when handling an error in a recursive-descent parser.  But the "normal" path is indeed to return all the way up through the calls.